# How to use wp_mail() function in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sbt'])) {
//user posted variables
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

//php mailer variables
  $to = get_option('aaaa@gmail.com');
  $subject = "Report";
  $headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

echo "check";

//Here put your Validation and send mail
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
      if($sent) {
      echo "sent";
      }//mail sent!
      else  {
      echo "failed";
      }//message wasn't sent
}
?>
```

I have developed a own word press site i need to use WP_mail() function to my contact form.

please help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this is example:

```
//user posted variables
$name = $_POST['message_name'];
$email = $_POST['message_email'];
$message = $_POST['message_text'];

//php mailer variables
$to = get_option('admin_email');
$subject = "Some text in subject...";
$headers = 'From: '. $email . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

//Here put your Validation and send mail
$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers);
    
if($sent) {
  //message sent!       
}
else  {
  //message wasn't sent       
}
```

Comment: i have implemented this example but still i am not receiving mail

Comment: thanks working fine...